# Simultaneous equations & critical points

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

I am trying to find and classify the critical points of:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3+y}{3x^2+y^2}$$

so far I have found the partial derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{3x^4+3y^2x^2-6xy}{(3x^2+y^2)^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{3x^2-2yx^3-y^2}{(3x^2+y^2)^2}$$

Setting them $=0$, $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ are obviously solutions with $(0,0)$ not existing. I can't see how to solve the system though.

Firstly, are there any solutions I've missed?

Secondly, what is the best way to go about classifying them?

Comment: Note that both are "quadratics" in y, and you can factorize numerators to find the zeros

Comment: @variable yes, fixed.